How to wrap the ckeditor editor in a div with a custom class?
ckeditor4 offered the "bodyclass" which I could use to add custom classes to the editor.
ckeditor5 removes bodyclass, in favor of adding a custom div around the editor with my classes (per their documentation under bodyclass).
But how? What is the process for something like this?
